# how to play upload audio on button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, audio

I have a code to play an audio when choosing file but i want to play audio on button click without storing it . but on button click its not working .
there is my blade file

```
 <label for="audioFile" class="input-label">Audio File</label>
                        <input type="file"  id="audioFile" class="form-control" name="audio-file[]" accept="audio/*"  >

                    <button onclick="fileSelect(event)" type="button"  style="color:cornflowerblue;border:white;background-color:white;"><i class="fa fa-volume-up test"></i></button>
           <audio id="audio-preview" ></audio>
```

This is the javascript code

```
function fileSelect(e){
   // console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
    var sound = document.getElementById('audio-preview');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        sound.src = this.result;
        sound.controls = true;
        sound.play();
        };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

And one more thing when audio is playing the multiplayer is not shown.
Please any one help to solve my issue .
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Where is your file input?

Comment: you need to have an input type="file" element to read that file, also bind that to change event instead of click

Comment: Onchange event is not working

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `FileReader` to get a base64 url. that's a wasteful round about way that requires encoding/decoding in vain. instead use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static)

```js
const selectFile = document.querySelector('#selectFile')
const audioFile = document.querySelector('#audioFile')
const sound = document.getElementById('audio-preview')

selectFile.addEventListener('click', () => audioFile.click())

function fileSelect (evt){
  sound.src = URL.createObjectURL(evt.target.files[0])
  sound.controls = true
  sound.play()
}

audioFile.addEventListener('change', fileSelect)
```

```html
<input type="file" id="audioFile" accept="audio/*">
<button id="selectFile">Select file</button>
<audio id="audio-preview"></audio><br>
<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light">
```